# Representing Duration (W3C Style) in Seconds VS Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: xml, w3c, duration

So the w3 standard for representing a duration, say in XML, is for example

```
<period>P5H3M32S</period>
```

(which is 5 hours, 3 minutes, 32 seconds)

Is it necessary to represent it like that?  Could I simply use

```
<period>PS18212</period>
```

which is 18,212 seconds which is the same value.

It would be nice to have a number that's easier to write and parse programatically.

Comment: The equivalent would be `P18212S`, not `PS18212`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's an ISO standard (8601) which W3C references, not a W3C standard. The two representations are equivalent. If you use the XPath constructor

```
xs:dayTimeDuration(period)
```

you will get the same value in both cases, and both are therefore equally easy to manipulate. For example

```
xs:dayTimeDuration(period) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')
```

gives you the number of seconds in the duration, regardless which representation was used.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I can represent it either way and it will be happily parsed.  I suppose dispalying many seconds is not as human readable but that's down to personal preference.